# Why PHPMailer needs an SMTP to send emails and postfix doesn't

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

i just installed postfix: it's sending email without any configuration by me. (I choosed no-config 
setup)

Can I know why phpmailer needs a valid smpt or relay to send emails while postfix doens't?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postfix is a mail server. phpmailer is a library to interface with a mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Because postfix **is** a SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well congratz, you have build yourself kind of an open relay then:)

Phpmailer needs server config as far as I could for now see when stumbling over their docs.

Postfix is a mail server which would be a layer under this, I suppose.

Comment: Well, bradley just summed it up more properly:)
Anyways. Please reassure that you are only able to send mail from local accounts if you are not completely configuring postfix.